# `connects_to` can only be called on ActiveRecord::Base or abstract classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails application I want to access some data from a second, non-standard (not complying to Rails conventions) database. The Ruby on Rails application should only read, but not write to this database.

In `config/database.yaml` I declare it like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

wn:
  <<: *default
  database: ~/dev/wn/wn.db
```

Then, I added the following class to `app/models` directory:

```
class CiHarvestRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "ciHarvest"
  connects_to database: { reading: :wn }
end
```

When I add the code

```
<% harvest_item = CiHarvestRecord.first
harvest_item 

   %>
```

and open the respective page, I get the error `connects_to` can only be called on ActiveRecord::Base or abstract classes`.

**How can I fix it, i. e. tell Rails that `CiHarvestRecord` is located a different (`wn`) database?**

I am using Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 6.1.3 on MacOS Big Sur.

**Update 1:** If I add the file `app/models/wn.rb` with the contents

```
class Wn < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  connects_to database: { reading: :wn }
end
```

then renamed `CiHarvestItem.rb` to `ci_harvest_item.rb` and now it contains this:

```
class CiHarvestRecord < Wn
  self.table_name = "ciHarvest"
end
```

Now I am getting the error `No connection pool for 'Wn' found.`.

**Update 2:**

I ran

```
cd db
ln -s ~/dev/wn/wn.db wn.db
```

then changed `database.yaml` to

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

wn:
  <<: *default
  database: db/wn.db
```

But I am still getting the same error as in update 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `connects_to database: { writing: :wn }`

When you specify only `reading:` keyword you will get this error `No connection pool for 'Wn' found`. You can only use `reading:` together with `writing:` when you have a read replica.

See docs for more info https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#horizontal-sharding

Answer (score 1):

Create an abstract class in `models/wn.rb` ...

```
class Wn < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  connects_to database: { reading: :wn }
end
```

then in `models/ci_harves_record.rb`

```
class CiHarvestRecord < Wn
  self.table_name = "ciHarvest"
end
```

Comment: I tried out your approach, see update 1 for results. Could it be that Rails cannot access my user directory and therefore cannot read the database at `~/dev/wn/wn.db`?

Comment: Also (sorry for a stupid question): When I modify `database.yaml`, am I supposed to run some tool thereafter (e. g. `rake`, DB migration)?

Comment: What kind of database is it?

Comment: SQLite 3. `development` database (which works) is also SQLite 3.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry, I see that now.  The `~/dev/wn/wn.db` path is using the home directory of the rails user... that's the same as your directory, right?

Comment: The rails project is located in `~/dev/misc/swp`. I run `bin/rails server`from `~/dev/misc/swp` directory. Because I suspected that the problem may be caused by Rails not being able to access `wn.db`, I a) added a symlink from `db/wn.db` to `~/dev/wn/wn.db` and modified `database.yml` accordingly (see update 2). It did not help. But maybe you can spot an error there.